# Reading int values from a vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector, numeric

I have a problem to read a large int ( `1 to 10^100` ) into `vector` the problem is I cannot read it as numeric `data-type` and split it into the vector so I want a solution to `read` the number separately into the `vector`

Example:

```
45686469
vec[0] = 4
vec[1] = 5
...
vec[7] = 9
```

Comment: What did you try when you attempted to do what you describe?

Comment: sorry I am newbie here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one possible way to do it:

```
std::string yourinput;
cin>>yourinput; //capture your large number as a string

std::vector<char> vch;

for(size_t st=0;st<yourinput.length();++st)
{
 vch.push_back(yourinput[st]); //move each character into the vector
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: or the much simpler: `std::vector<char> vch { yourinput.begin(), yourinput.end() };`.